# How to set up an NFS server on ubuntu?

Tags: nfs, xbmc

How do I make my ubuntu install an NFS server. So that it is accessible to another system running XBMC on my network?

Output of `exportfs -v`:

```
root@amith-dualcore:# exportfs -v
/media/amith/Amith-Deskt
        192.168.1.0/24(rw,async,wdelay,insecure,root_squash,no_subtree_check,fsid=0)
```

The client is running xbian on a Raspberry Pi, having XBMC 12.0-RC1.

Comment: package `nfs-kernel-server`? And then refresh the exports? `sudo exportfs -a` And how exactly are you mounting?

Comment: Please include the output of `exportfs -v` in your question and what kind of XBMC this is. Running on Ubuntu? On an embedded media device? Do you have a regular Ubuntu machine to test the server on? And have you tried `192.168.1.0/24` as host range? As a `*` will make it a hostname.

Comment: @gertvdijk Updated. Yes, I have used `192.168.1.0/24`

Answer (score 1):

There is an official document about that explains it:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.